# Why don't we have a Coordinate Geometry tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

I recently came across [this] question and thought that it should be tagged "Coordinate-Geometry". However, to my astonishment, no such tag exists. Why is it so?

I finally created that tag. I do not know the formal procedure for a tag creation. Does just putting it to a question creates a tag or do the mods look at it afterwards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because we already have [analytic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-geometry).

See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry). I have inserted a synonym for coordinate geometry to the [analytic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-geometry) tag.

---

For the second part of the question, yes, just creating it will do. Some mods (like yours truly) would do drive-by clean-up of the tags every now and then. So if we spot a new tag that is a synonym of an established old one, we will usually just silently merge the new into the old and set-up a "tag synonym".

If you are really not sure whether a tag should belong, you can always make a [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) question of it.

If you fully expect a tag to be there but could not find it, it may help also to ask around on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics). People have been around longer may be more familiar with the quirks with our tagging system. (For example, that we have a [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) for the two subjects under one heading is historical [someone made a choice early on] and to disentangle the two just seems too much work with too little gain.)

Comment: I figured it out almost immediately and was about to delete the question.

Comment: In the case of Meta, honest questions almost always deserve to stay. Someone else may have a similar question with regards to some other tag, and in which case I will not have to re-write the answer again if this one is available. `:-)` I always think it is a good idea for new users to ask about "stuff" on meta. It keeps us on our toes about what we consider "obvious" and "well-known" and "settled". And it helps make the whole site more friendly to new users.